# CvBridge: depth registration for depth and rgb opencv images and convert to ros image msg

Tags: ros, cvbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What I want to do basically is publishing depth_registred image on topic.
I already have opencv depth and rgb images and the transformation between them.
I wonder should I finish depth registration first and then use CvBridge to convert it to ros image msg or convert depth and rgb images to two ros image msgs and finish depth registration?
I have tried the first way but I am stuck at the step of converting to ros image msg since I can't find specific encoding for RGBD image.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280124/cvbridge:-depth-registration-for-depth-and-rgb-opencv-images-and-convert-to-ros-image-msg/) by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2018-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All the RGB-D cameras I've worked with in ROS publish their RGB and depth (registered) on different image topics. There is no RGB-D type as far as I know,  it would be messy anyway because the depth channel is usually a positive floating point channel (in meters) and the RGB channels are 8 bit intensities. You could maybe get away with a 4 channel float image but it would not be the most bandwidth efficient.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on 2018-01-18**:
But when launching Kinect2 on ROS by freenect_camera package, it does publish depth_registered image on topic. Hence I wonder how does it get depth_registered image.

**Comment by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on 2018-01-18**:
Sorry, it is my bad. I misunderstood the meaning of depth_registered image. I thought it is RGBD image. Thanks for your help.